# Different output between command line and crontab

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, command-line, cron

I'm trying to send an alert whenever a connection between 2 different machines gets lost.

Basically I need to see from PC N°2 if there is an established connection from PC N°4 to port 6031 on PC N°5.

PC N°2 has ubuntu server 16.04, 4 and 5, Windows Server 2012.

Actually I can see the connection, but can't send the alert.

I'm currently using this little script.

```bsh
alerta=$(sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@10.8.0.4 netstat -na | grep "6031")

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    (Here goes a code that sends a SMS to my phone saying everything is ok)
else [[ $alerta ]]; then
    (Here goes a code that sends a SMS to my phone saying something is not ok)
fi
```

This is the output when I run the command in command line.

```
user2@pc2:~$ sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@10.8.0.4 netstat -na | grep "6031"
  TCP    10.8.0.4:54961      10.8.0.5:6031       ESTABLISHED
cra@atlas:~$
```

And it works, but when I use crontab it just sends the "error" message.

The command works on root and user accounts, it's just when I try to make it work with cron when it fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The script seems to lack a `#!` line saying it should be executed by `bash`. By default, commands in crontabs are executed by `/bin/sh`, which may or may not understand `[[ ... ]]`, for example.

Comment: See [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) for some good troubleshooting steps. The ones I'd concentrate on: capture output and errors as it runs, and check environment dependencies (e.g. is `sshpass` in crond's bare-minimum default `PATH`?).

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda, I alrady tried with #!/usr/bin/env bash and #!/usr/bin/bash. And without any of them. Same result.

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson, just tailed the /var/lig/syslog and all I got is
`Aug  2 19:12:01 atlas CRON[10393]: (root) CMD (/home/user2/test.sh)`
Now I'm searching how to check if sshpass is in cron's PATH.

Comment: There is no `/usr/bin/bash` in Ubuntu, it's `/bin/bash`. And that looks like it needs an `elif`, not an `else`